# cmdline.txt appears to be empty after editing it

Tags: boot, cmdline.txt

I've edited **cmdline.txt** on my Raspberry 3b + model to not show the logo during the start up. I've added ***logo.nologo*** at the end of a line.

After that, I restarted the device, but I was still seeing the splash screen logo. I figured out I might've done something wrong while editing the cmdline.txt so I opened it again but it was empty.

Raspbian boots up correctly, even though cmdline.txt appears to be empty. Any clue why is this happening?

Comment: How do you edit `/boot/cmdline.txt`? What editor do you use? Do you see the contents with `sudo cat /boot/cmdline.txt`? What does `sudo ls -l /boot/cmdline.txt` show? Can you edit with `sudo -e /boot/cmdline.txt`? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can see what the kernel has used as /boot/cmdline.txt by `cat /proc/cmdline` there's some stuff there that's merged in by the bootcode.

If you're using NOOBS (or PINN) the command line you're editing may not be the command line that's being used for booting. Use the NOOBS recovery console (by tapping `[SHIFT]` during boot and you can edit the Raspbian command line from that recovery system.

The stock command line for plain Raspbian looks like:

`dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=9f3d5e5a-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles`